# Regex To Get Captured Group Until Reaching Another Section

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Trying to figure out a RegEx to capture multiple instances of a group but only up to a certain point.

Ex:

```
START

City: Los Angeles
- Item: 48
- Item: 57
- Item: 92
- Item: 77

City: Austin
- Item: 44
- Item: 88

END
```

I'm trying to write a regex that will return JUST the Los Angeles items (ex: 48,57,92,77).  The pattern below captures all of them but I just want Los Angeles.

```
 -\s*Item:\s*(?<itemnum>[0-9]{1,5})
```

Is this possible with 1 regex?

Comment: Do you always want the first city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may use a regex like

```
(?m)^City:\s*Los Angeles(?:\s*-\s*Item:\s*(?<itemnum>\d+))+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5ECity%3A%5Cs*Los%20Angeles%28%3F%3A%5Cs*-%5Cs*Item%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3Citemnum%3E%5Cd%2B%29%29%2B&i=START%0D%0A%0D%0ACity%3A%20Los%20Angeles%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2048%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2057%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2092%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2077%0D%0A%0D%0ACity%3A%20Austin%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2044%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2088%0D%0A%0D%0AEND). You need to use `Regex.Matches` and access the Group "itemnum" capture stack to retrieve all the values.

**Pattern details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `City:\s*Los Angeles` - `City:`, 0+ whitespaces, `Los Angeles`
- `(?:\s*-\s*Item:\s*(?<itemnum>\d+))+` -  one or more occurrences of:

  - `\s*-\s*` - a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `Item:` - a literal `Item:` substring
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?<itemnum>\d+)` - Group "itemnum": one or more digits.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/yo8OMg):

```
var s = "START\r\n\r\nCity: Los Angeles\r\n- Item: 48\r\n- Item: 57\r\n- Item: 92\r\n- Item: 77\r\n\r\nCity: Austin\r\n- Item: 44\r\n- Item: 88\r\n";
var pattern = @"(?m)^City:\s*Los Angeles(?:\s*-\s*Item:\s*(?<itemnum>\d+))+";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
   .Cast<Match>().SelectMany(p => p.Groups["itemnum"].Captures
        .Cast<Capture>()
        .Select(x => x.Value));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
// => 48, 57, 92, 77
```

Alternative solution: using a `\G` based pattern:

```
(?m)(?:^City:\s*Los Angeles|\G(?!\A))\s*-\s*Item:\s*(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3A%5ECity%3A%5Cs*Los%20Angeles%7C%5CG%28%3F!%5CA%29%29%5Cs*-%5Cs*Item%3A%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29&i=START%0D%0A%0D%0ACity%3A%20Los%20Angeles%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2048%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2057%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2092%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2077%0D%0A%0D%0ACity%3A%20Austin%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2044%0D%0A-%20Item%3A%2088%0D%0A%0D%0AEND). Basically, it is the same (`(?:^City:\s*Los Angeles|\G(?!\A))` matches `City: Los Angeles` and subsequent matches are only allowed at the end of the previous match end location), but retrieval is easier:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
   .Cast<Match>()
   .Select(p => p.Groups["itemnum"].Value)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor.  The first pattern only returned the last item (77) for me but the \G based solution worked!  Thx!

Comment: @MikeSmith Strange, the first one should work alright. You probably did not use my code.